# how to set /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled to 'never' on coreos

Tags: mongodb, docker, coreos

I have just updated MongoDB to the latest 3.2 version on a test CoreOS server. But get this warnings:

```
CONTROL [initandlisten] 
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** We suggest setting it to 'never'
CONTROL [initandlisten] 
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
CONTROL [initandlisten] ** We suggest setting it to 'never'
CONTROL [initandlisten]
```

following https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/550 does not seem to work on CoreOS

is there a way in which to set kernel memory-management parameter globally?

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: i came across the following. https://gist.github.com/PyYoshi/a7ca64b6c92b5ef1834b i hope this helps

Comment: nice one, thank you